# Tikz flow chart nodes not aligned

Tags: tikz-arrows, flow-charts

Example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, arrows, positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\tikzset{%
    decision/.style = {diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=3.5cm},
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum width=3.5cm},
    io/.style ={trapezium, draw, minimum width=2.5cm,trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120},
    line/.style = {draw, -stealth},
    cloud/.style = {draw, rectangle, fill=red!20, minimum height=2em, minimum width=1.5cm, rounded corners=10pt}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
>=triangle 60,
\matrix[matrix of nodes, column sep=2cm, row sep=1cm]{%
    \node [decision] (c) {abc fffffffffffffff};&
    \node [block]    (d) {def ffffffffffffffffffffffff ss} ; &\\
};
% Draw edges
\path [line] (c) -- (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

How to make sure the arrow is always flat / horizontal no matter what the content of the nodes is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is actually `matrix of nodes`. The misalignment comes from the fact that both nodes are anchored at the `base` anchor due to `matrix of nodes`, while in your case you want them to be anchored at `center`.

Note that the purpose of `matrix of nodes` is so one can avoid writing all of `\node [<options>] (foo) {text};`, it lets you write `|[<options>]| text` directly, where `|[<options>]|` is optional. As you're not actually using that feature in the code you show, you could possibly just remove the `matrix of nodes` option, and you get the alignment you're after.

Another option is to add `anchor=center` to the node styles you use. That will overwrite the setting done by `matrix of nodes`.

In the third `tikzpicture` below I show how you can use `matrix of nodes`. The nodes in such a matrix are named automatically, based on row and column.

Final note: you had an empty cell in the matrix which caused extra whitespace on the right side. I removed the final `&` for this reason.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, arrows, positioning}
\tikzset{%
    decision/.style = {diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=3.5cm},
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum width=3.5cm},
    io/.style ={trapezium, draw, minimum width=2.5cm,trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120},
    line/.style = {draw, -stealth},
    cloud/.style = {draw, rectangle, fill=red!20, minimum height=2em, minimum width=1.5cm, rounded corners=10pt}
    }
\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\matrix[column sep=2cm, row sep=1cm]{%
    \node [decision] (c) {abc fffffffffffffff};&
    \node [block]    (d) {def ffffffffffffffffffffffff ss} ; \\
};
% Draw edges
\path [line] (c) -- (d);
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{ %%% add anchor=center
  decision/.append style={anchor=center},
  block/.append style={anchor=center}
  }

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\matrix[column sep=2cm, row sep=1cm]{%
    \node [decision] (c) {abc fffffffffffffff};&
    \node [block]    (d) {def ffffffffffffffffffffffff ss} ; \\
};
% Draw edges
\path [line] (c) -- (d);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

\matrix[matrix of nodes, column sep=2cm, row sep=1cm] (m) {%
    |[decision]| abc fffffffffffffff&
    |[block]| def ffffffffffffffffffffffff ss \\
};
% Draw edges
\path [line] (m-1-1) -- (m-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```